# Distribute binary library on OSX

Tags: c, macos

I'm planning to release some compiled code that shall be linked by client applications on MacOSX.

The distribution is some kind of code library and a set of header files defining the public interface for the library.The code is internally C++ but its public interface (i.e what's being shown in the headers) is completely C.

These are my requirements or atleast what I hope I can accomplish:

- I want my library to be as agnostic
  as possible for what version of OSX
  and GCC the user is running. Having
  separate libraries for 64 bit and 32
  bit is okay though.
- I want my library
  to be loadable from languages that
  supports loading C libraries such as
  python or similar.
- I want my
  libraries internal symbols to be
  isolated from the code it's being
  linked into. I don't want to have
  duplicate symbol errors because we
  happen to name an internal function
  in the same way. My C++ code is properly namespaced so this may not be as big of an issue though, but some of the libraries I depend on is C and can be an issue (see next point).
- I want my library
  dependencies to be safe. My library
  depends on some libraries such as
  libpng, boost and stl and I don't
  want issues because some users don't
  necessarily have all of them installed
  or get problems because they have
  been compiled with other flags or
  have different versions than I have.

On Windows I use a DLL with an export library and link all my dependencies statically into the dll. It fulfills all the criteria above and if I can get the same result on OSX it would be great, however I've heard that dynamic libraries tend not to isolate symbols on mac in the same way.

Is there some kind of best practice for this on OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal OS X .dylib pretty much satisfies your requirements, with the note that you will want to have an exports file that the linker uses to determine exactly which symbols are exported (to prevent leaking your internal symbols).

In order to make your own library dependencies safe, you will probably need to either include those libraries with yours or link them statically into your library.

**edit:** To answer your follow-up question of how to apply an exports file to a link command, the man page for `ld` has the following to say:

```
 -exported_symbols_list filename
     The specified filename contains a list of global symbol names
     that will remain as global symbols in the output file.  All
     other global symbols will be treated as if they were marked
     as __private_extern__ (aka visibility=hidden) and will not be
     global in the output file. The symbol names listed in file-
     name must be one per line.  Leading and trailing white space
     are not part of the symbol name.  Lines starting with # are
     ignored, as are lines with only white space.  Some wildcards
     (similar to shell file matching) are supported.  The *
     matches zero or more characters.  The ? matches one charac-
     ter.  [abc] matches one character which must be an 'a', 'b',
     or 'c'.  [a-z] matches any single lower case letter from 'a'
     to 'z'.
```

So, if your library had only two functions that you wanted to be public, lets call them `foo` and `bar`, and they were C functions (so the symbol names aren't mangled), your exports file (let's call it `myLibrary.exports`) would contain these two lines:

```
_foo
_bar
```

and maybe some comments, etc.  When you do the final link step to build the library, you would pass the `-exported_symbols_list myLibrary.exports` flag to the linker.  This has the additional benefit that the link will fail if you don't provide one of the exported symbols; this can catch a lot of "oops, I forgot to include that file in the build" mistakes.

You don't need to use the command-line tools to do all this, of course.  In the build settings for a dynamic library in XCode, you will find `Exported Symbols File` (undefined by default); set it to the path to your exports file there and it will be passed to the linker.

Comment: This seems like a good solution. Do you have any good reference on how to create an exports file?

Comment: I added some detail on how to use an exports file; for how to create one, if the library isn't too big I usually use nm to get a list of all the symbols and then remove the ones that I want to keep private.  For large projects, this isn't really a viable approach, so I usually write scripts to generate the file for me.

Comment: Also note that there's no need for separate 32- and 64-bit libraries; OS X allows dylibs that support multiple architectures.  It's a little convoluted from the command line, but if you're using XCode it should Just Work.

Comment: Thanks. With the addition, it is pretty much exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

The key term you need is 'framework'. You need to create a 'universal' framework that is self-contained. ('Universal' is Apple-ease for 'compile several times and package into one library.) It's not as straightforward as on Windows in terms of encapsulation, but the necessary linker options are there.